# How to check banned ports?

Tags: ssh, ftp, cpanel

I need to check if I can connect to a cpanel, FTP or SSH. Is there anyway to check if a port is banned?

p.s. I'm living in a Dormitory so I have no control over modems or etc.

Comment: "Banned" on which end? Your client, or the remote server? In either case, `nmap` should be some help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nc` (netcat) to check whether a port is reachable:

```
nc -vz hostname port
```

If a port is reachable is will give you for example:

```
nc -vz 8.8.8.8 53
Connection to 8.8.8.8 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!
```